# I can't figure out why my Socket.io listener triggers once but then doesn't trigger even if more emits come from the back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I'm making a clone of discord and right now I'm trying to implement the online/offline functionality of the server users. I'm trying to implement it like this:

When a user joins a server, I emit a `userCameOnline` event with the username of the user:

```
state.socket.emit('userCameOnline', state.username)
```

Then on the back-end, I listen for that event and once I receive it, I set the socket's username to the emitted username, then push that username to an array of online users and finally, I emit back an event called `onlineUsers`:

```
socket.on('userCameOnline', (username) => {
    socket.username = username
    onlineUsers.push(socket.username)
    console.log(onlineUsers)
    socket.emit('onlineUsers', onlineUsers)
})
```

And this is the onlineUsers listener on the front-end that sets `onlineUsers` property to the server:

```
state.socket.on('onlineUsers', (onlineUsers) => {
    console.log(onlineUsers)
    server.onlineUsers = onlineUsers
})
```

Now here's the problem. The `onlineUsers` listener works when I load the page the first time, however, when I open a second browser and join the chat with another account, the client emits these events again with the new user:

```
state.socket.emit('userCameOnline', state.username)
```

I know this is working fine as I console.log(onlineUsers) on the back-end and see that the array indeed has 2 users once the second client has joined. This means that this works:

```
socket.on('userCameOnline', (username) => {
    socket.username = username
    onlineUsers.push(socket.username)
    console.log(onlineUsers)
    socket.emit('onlineUsers', onlineUsers)
})
```

Unfortunately, the `onlineUsers` listener on the first client doesn't trigger which means that the `onlineUsers` property of the server doesn't get updated with the newly joined user. I've been banging my head for some time now and I can't figure out why is this happening. I've been following the trail and console.logging everything but I still can't figure it out.

This is why I am wondering why does this:

```
state.socket.on('onlineUsers', (onlineUsers) => {
    console.log(onlineUsers)
    server.onlineUsers = onlineUsers
})
```

Triggers once I load the page and then doesn't trigger anymore even though I'm emitting the event from the back-end every time a new user joins the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if i understand your problem then instead of emitting in the Back-end:

```
socket.emit('onlineUsers', onlineUsers)
```

You should emit :

```
io.emit('onlineUsers', onlineUsers)
```

Because by emitting with **socket.emit()** you will end up emitting only to the same client that emitted to the server in the first place. 
As with **io.emit()** you will emit to all of your clients.

---

Assuming that you are using something like :
`const io = require('socket.io')(server, {(your_args)})`

If you want to check for further information on how to use the **emit** function
check out this page https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/ from their website.

---

Finally i would highly recommend you to check out their API documentation and other blogs about it